# Matrix exponential - inequality

Tags: normed-spaces

Hi so I'm supposed to solve an inequality about Matrix exponentials. I'm pretty sure it follows directly from some theorem but I just can't seem to find it in my script.

Let $A = (a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ be a square matrix with real coefficients. We set $\lVert A \rVert$ $=$ max$_{1\leq i,j\leq n} \lvert a_{ij} \rvert$. Show that for every integer $k \geq 1$, the inequality $\lVert A^k \rVert \leq n^{k-1} \lVert A \rVert^k$ holds.

Now I've seen some different inequalities and proofs, however I don't really know how to approach this. In general, I think it would make sense to prove it via induction, although it seems to me that there is a much simpler proof. I've tried doing that, however I'm not sure how to work with $\lVert A^k \rVert $and$ \lVert A \rVert^k$ as for the first the exponent is inside the norm and for the second it isn't. How can I go about proving such an inequality?

Comment: These are not matrix exponentials, but powers of matrices.  A matrix exponential looks like $e^A$ for a matrix $A$.

Comment: @saulspatz you're right, my bad.

Comment: No problem.  I suggest you try this for $2\times2$ matrices, and small values of $n$ to get a feel for the theorem.

Comment: Why does it seem to you that there's a simpler proof than induction? The induction seems entirely straighforward: it's clear for $k=1$, then for the induction stepp you just have to show that $||A^{k+1}||\le n||A||\,||A^k||$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I thought there was an easier way but I might be mixing up some things. That's what I also wrote down. However I do not know how to proceed from the fact that one of the exponents is inside the norm and the other is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > **Lemma** If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ then $||AB||\le||A||\,||B||$.

Proof: Say $A=(a_{jk})$, $B=(b_{jk})$ and $AB=(c_{jk})$. Various definitions show that $$|a_{jk}|\le||A||,$$ $$|b_{jk}|\le||B||,$$and $$c_{jk}=\sum_{l=1}^na_{jl}b_{lk}.$$ So $$|c_{jk}|\le\sum_{l=1}^n|a_{jl}|\,|b_{lk}|\le\sum_{l=1}^n||A||\,||B||=n||A||\,||B||.$$

This takes care of the induction step in the inequality you ask about. Assume $||A^k||\le n^{k-1}||A||^k$. Then $$||A^{k+1}||=||AA^k||\le n||A||\,||A^k||\le n||A||n^{k-1}||A||^k= n^{(k+1)-1}||A||^{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to admit I could not have done this myself, but now that I see how you solved this problem, it does make sense. I will try myself now and hope to get the same result.